# Replaying a gif from start with createElement in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a function in my React project that will create a new element that plays one loop of a gif, then deletes the element. So far I have been semi-successful using this:

```
function playGif() {
    var gif = document.createElement('img')
    gif.className = "gif-play"
    document.body.appendChild(gif)
    setTimeout(() => {  gif.parentNode.removeChild(gif); }, 600)
  }
```

With the following CSS:

```
.gif-play {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(./assets/images/animations/atk1.gif);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

However, no matter what I set the timeout to delete the element (even the precise duration of the gif in milliseconds) the gif will still start clipping and playing from the middle after several button clicks.

I have also tried setting the image src directly like this:

```
  function playGif() {
    var gif = document.createElement('img')
    gif.src = require('./assets/images/animations/atk1.gif')
    document.body.appendChild(gif)
    setTimeout(() => {  gif.parentNode.removeChild(gif); }, 600)
  }
```

But with this the gif never shows up at all, just a broken image. I thought using require() in React was supposed to fix that, but it still doesn't work for me.

So any tips on how to get my gif to play from the beginning when I call the function would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you want but I have prepared one animation for you. You can check it. Hope it helps you.

**PlayGifExample Component**

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import PlayGif from './PlayGif.css'

function PlayGifExample() {

    function animate(i) {
        if(i > 1000)
            return;
        let gif = document.createElement('img');
        gif.className = "gif-play";
        gif.style.cssText = `left: ${i}px`;
        console.log(i);
        document.body.appendChild(gif);
        setTimeout(() => {
            gif.parentNode.removeChild(gif);
            animate(i+1);
        }, 10)
    }

    function playGif() {
            let gif = document.createElement('img');
            gif.className = "gif-play";
            gif.style.cssText = `left: 1px`;
            document.body.appendChild(gif);
            setTimeout(() => {
                gif.parentNode.removeChild(gif);
                animate(2);
            }, 10)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={playGif}>Click me</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default PlayGifExample;
```

**PlayGif.css**

```
.gif-play {
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(./images/4.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```